# jax-ws how to include xml schema in wsdl instead of xsd import?

Tags: xml, wsdl, schema, jax-ws

I noticed that my wsdl has a xsd:import to import the xml schema from a url. What do I have to do to display the xml schema in the wsdl itself? I anticipate that another team who will be consuming my web service will require it. I don't know why they would need it but I want to know how to do it if they ask.

```
<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8081/MySoapFaultExample/myservice?xsd=1" namespace="http://ws.companyname.com/"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the whole xml schema instead of the `<xsd:import>` element. A simple example just to see how it will look like:

```
<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:element name="GetProductInfo">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="productName" type="string"/>
                <xsd:element name="productCode" type="integer"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

You can find the WSDL basics in the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_wsdl_documents.asp) and some WSDL examples explained in [here](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/14-annotated-WSDL-examples).